# Is not empty string not working for special characters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I recently find out that the check I am using for empty string is not working for some of the data. I am using:

```
[DataField] <> ''
```

And for some characters it seems to not work:

[image]

For example, the following yields `1`:

```
SELECT IIF(N'' = '', 1, 0);
```

It seems, that the `ASCII` code for all of this is `63`:

```
SELECT ASCII(N'');
SELECT ASCII(N'');
SELECT ASCII(N'');
SELECT ASCII(N'');
SELECT ASCII(N'');
SELECT ASCII(N'☕');
```

In the [table](http://www.asciitable.com/) it is `?`.

If I use, `CHAR(63)` the check is working:

```
SELECT IIF(CHAR(63) <> '', 1, 0); -- 1
SELECT IIF(N'' <> '', 1, 0);    -- 0
```

Of course, I just change the check to be `LEN([DataField]) > 0` and now everything is fine. Just wondering, can anyone explain, why the initial check fails?

Comment: Emojis are Unicode and yet you put them inside ASCII strings. Add the N prefix

Comment: lol - love how even the link here prints the emojis

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Xax, yes, thanks.

Comment: NB: From the documentation for [`Len()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql): "Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression, **excluding trailing blanks**."